# added new class in CSS file, but it is not showing up in the browser developer tools>CSS option

Tags: asp.net, css, dynamic, controls

I added a new class in the existing css file in my project. The new class is as follows:

```
.backgroundBoxStyle
{
    background-color:Blue;
}
```

I am dynamically creating a control on the runtime. So, for example, in case of a Panel, I want to assign a css class style of - backgroundBoxStyle to it.
I do it like this in my code which creates the control to load.

```
ctrlToAdd = GetControl("Panel", smallTable)
Dim ctrlToAddwebControl As WebControls.WebControl
ctrlToAddwebControl = CType(ctrlToAdd, WebControls.WebControl)
CType(ctrlToAddwebControl, Panel).Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
```

I tried the following options but none are working:

```
ctrlToAddwebControl.CssClass = "backgroundBoxStyle"
ctrlToAddwebControl.Attributes.Add("class", "backgroundBoxStyle")
ctrlToAddwebControl.Style.Add("class", "backgroundBoxStyle")
CType(ctrlToAddwebControl, Panel).CssClass = "backgroundBoxStyle"
CType(ctrlToAddwebControl, Panel).Style("class") = "backgroundBoxStyle"
```

I am able to assing a background color using this statement:

```
CType(ctrlToAddwebControl, Panel).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MintCream
```

But I want to read the background color from the CSS file.
Please help.

Comment: In what event are you adding your control to the page?

Comment: using containerControl.Controls.Add(displayTable), where displayTable has the Panel created.

Comment: If you look at the generated HTML, does the control show up with its attributes?